# Software which can find a complete video in the internet using one of its sequences

Tags: windows, android, open-source, web-apps, video

I have downloaded a compilation video recently and some parts of it were so interesting that I'm eager to find their complete videos.

I know they are somewhere on the internet but don't know where.

- The sequences are short (10-15 seconds each).
- For Windows or Android, please.

Comment: Take sceenshot of video and search images on Google image search

Answer (score 0):

Make a screenshot and upload it to Yandex reverse image search, i.e.
https://yandex.com/images/ → Camera icon → Select a file.

If there are no results, try with other video frames that look a bit different.

To do the same with fewer clicks, open the local video file in the browser (for example Chrome can play local video files) and use for example [this extension](https://github.com/dessant/search-by-image) in the Capture mode.